# QAbstractTableModel empty last row, without sorting

Tags: c++, qt, sorting

I have my own table model (DragDropTableModel) subclassed from QAbstractTableModel. Inside it I would like for the last row to remain always empty.

I implement it by adding insertRows() into setData() function:

```
bool  DragDropTableModel  :: setData (const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{ 
...   
  if (role == Qt::EditRole) 
    {
      ...
      if (row == this->rowCount() - 1)
         insertRows(this->rowCount(), 1);
    }
}
```

After that I have QSortFilterProxyModel installed on it. The problem is: when I do sorting, the last row is also sorted. But I want to make it not obeying sorting and to stand on the same last position. So no matter the sorting order is (Ascending or Descending) the last row should always be empty.

How to make it? May be I should use another approach to realize "making empty row" in my model?

Comment: IMHO the only way is to subclass QSortFilterProxyModel and implement expected behaviour in its lessThan() method . "Taint" you row by setting some special value in its some kind of customRole , and always treat is as needed

Comment: If I reimplement only lessThan() in QSortFilterProxyModel, I think it's impossible to do that empty string would be the last one in both orders of sorting: ascending and descending.

Comment: who says it has to be an empty string?  (look here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum for Qt::UserRole). so: for each column of that special row call model->setdata(index, "FAKEROW" Qt::UserRole). then in your function do `if item->data(Qt::UserRole) == "FAKEROW" return sortOrder() == Qt::Ascending) else return (call the same function from parent class)`. (maybe there should be comparsion to `Qt::Descending`, but you'll figure it out). should work. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, murison. Your idea worked.
I set up a value "EMPTY_ROW" for Qt::UserRole for the items of empty row. After that I reimplemented lessThan() method in QSortFilterProxyModel:

```
bool MySortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, const QModelIndex &right) const
{
    if (left.data(Qt::UserRole) == "EMPTY_ROW")
        return (this->sortOrder() == Qt::DescendingOrder);
    else if (right.data(Qt::UserRole) == "EMPTY_ROW")
        return (this->sortOrder() == Qt::AscendingOrder);
    else
        return QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(left, right);
}
```

So this row always appears in the bottom of the table after sorting. 
Also it's nescesary not to forget to clear Qt::UserRole when this empty row is filled with data.